# Threading - The fastest way to handle reoccuring threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

I am writing my first threaded application for an industrial machine that has a very fast line speed.  I am using the MFC for the UI and once the user pushes the "Start" machine button, I need to be simultaneously executing three operations.  I need to collect data, process it and output results very quickly as well as checking to see if the user has turned the machine "off".  When I say very quickly, I expect the analyze portion of the execution to take the longest and it needs to happen in well under a second.  I am mostly concerned about overhead elimination associated with threads.  What is the fastest way to implement the loop below:

```
void Scanner(CString& m_StartStop) {

    std::thread Collect(CollectData);

    while (m_StartStop == "Start") {

         Collect.join();
         std::thread Analyze(AnalyzeData);
         std::thread Collect(CollectData);

         Analyze.join();
         std::thread Send(SendData);
         Send.join();
     }
}
```

I realize this sample is likely way off base, but hopefully it gets the point across.  Should I be creating three threads and suspending them instead of creating and joining them over and over?  Also, I am a little unclear if the UI needs its own thread since the user needs to able to pause or stop the line at anytime.

In case anyone is wondering why this needs to be threaded as opposed to sequential, the answer is that the line speed of the machine will cause the need to be collecting data for the second part while the first part is being analyzed.  Every 1 second equates to 3 ft of linear part movement down this machine.

Comment: All UI operations must occur from the same thread, Windows isn't set up to work any other way. And any complex data structure, even something as simple as a CString, needs to be protected against simultaneous access between threads.

Comment: I understand, I guess what I am really asking is if the UI is a parent thread or if it is just another child.

Comment: MFC will assume it's being run from the parent thread, and to avoid trouble it would be safest to stick to that.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about functionnal problem before thinking about implementation.

So we have a continuous flow of data that need to be collected, analyzed and sent elsewhere, with a supervision point to be able to stop of pause the process.

- collection should be limited by the input flow
- analyze should only be cpu limited
- sending should be io bound

You just need to make sure that the slowest part must be collection.

That is a correct use case for threads. Implementation could use:

- a pool of *input buffers* that would be filled by collect task and used by analyze task
- one thread that continuously:

  - controls if it should exit (a dedicated variable)
  - takes an input object from the pool
  - fills it with data
  - passes it to analyze task
- one thread that continuously

  - waits for the first of an input object from collect task and a request to exit
  - analyzes the object and prepares output
  - send the output

  Optionnaly, you can have a separate thread for processing the output. In that case, the last lines becomes

  - passes an output object to the sending task

  and we must add:
- one thread that continuously

  - waits for the first of an output object from analze task and a request to exit
  - send the output

And you must provide a way to signal the request for pause or exit, either with a completely external program and a signalisation mechanism, or a GUI thread

Answer (score 0):

Any threads you need should already be running, waiting for work. You should not create or join threads.

If job A has to finish before job B can start, the completion of job A should trigger the start of job B. That is, when the thread doing job A finished doing job A, it should either do job B itself or trigger the dispatch of job B. There shouldn't need to be some other thread that's waiting for job A to finish so that it can start job B.

Comment: Perhaps I have been ineffective at communicating my issue.  On the first execution cycle B is waiting for A.  But on the second and further cycle, A is collecting information, while B is analyzing the previous cycle from A.  They must both be working simultaneously because there is not enough time for both operations to complete sequentially.

Comment: Then the code that collects information should dispatch the analysis of the information when it finishes collecting it. You shouldn't have a thread waiting around for something to happen so that it can tell another thread to do something.

Comment: ok thank you.  That is helpful.  So basically, I interpret that answer as saying that as each thread completes its task it should be destroyed.  Then another should be created to do the same task a short time later.  Is that correct?  Also, is the overhead significant in terms of time to create threads and destroy them?  Keep in mind I will be racing against the clock.  FYI, a 168 byte chunk of information is coming in every 8ms.

Comment: Those chunks will be collected for roughly 1 second and then sent onto the analyze portion.  Then repeat.

Comment: @bluebass44 No, the thread should not be destroyed. The thread should go on to do the next thing that needs to be done. Why destroy a perfectly good thread?

Comment: ok lets try again in a different way...So if a thread does all 3 functions (collect, analyze and send).  In theory could I just have 2 threads doing the exact same thing just offset in time?  In other words  thread (T) 1 is collecting information and when it finishes collecting I fire off T2 that starts collecting while T1 analyzes and sends?  Then if T1 is complete sending when T2 finishes collecting, T1 begins collecting again and the cycle repeats?

Comment: Sure. You can have a queue of work that needs to be done and a pool of threads that service that queue.